# How can I get the value by index of the dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, key

[**Enter image description here (the code)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap4GD.jpg)

**How can I get the value by key index, or may I, or there are other ways to match alphabet characters with morse characters?** I’am a child and beginner, so if you don’t understand my question ask me. I will try to be more clear.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the key values of a dict via the command `'dictname'.keys()` with dictname being the name of your dictionary.

I will not post any more information or comment any other parts of your code (unless you want me to) because maybe you want to figure it out by yourself. You shall test/print the command i gave you above and try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over a string. On each iteration `i` is the next character in the string.

```
>>> for i in 'ABCDE':
    print(i)

    
A
B
C
D
E
>>>
```

You [access the values in a dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) with a [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) (`[]`) using the keys for the subscript.

```
>>> d = {'A':'*-','B':'-***'}
>>> d['A']
'*-'

>>> for i in 'AB':
    print(d[i])

    
*-
-***
```

---

As a beginner, the more time you spend reading/consulting [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/) the faster you will progress. Just getting familiar with the *structure* of the documentation so you have an idea where to look for an answer will help a lot.

If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Another technique is to step through your program line by line as if you are the interpreter using a pencil and paper to keep track of variables, the expression results, conditional results...

[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)